# Serve React app via custom Express server while keeping automatic updates during development

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I have a React app and a *separate* Express server app.

I can serve my React app using a custom express server by using this code in my Express app:

```js
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/frontend/build/index.html"));
});
```

This works great, but by doing this I lose the ability for React to automatically update my app as I make changes. This is because I'm loading `index.html` from my React build folder. So to see any changes I make I have to stop the Express app, rebuild my React app and restart the Express app.

Is there any way I can modify the code above or do something else to make sure the React app keeps automatically updating in browser in the dev environment?

My npm script looks like this:

```sh
npm run build --prefix frontend && node server.js
```

`./` is a Node app which is my Express server

`./frontend` is a separate Node app which houses my React app

Thanks!

Comment: By "I have a React app", do you mean that you have access to its source files?

Comment: The word "separate" is emphasized, but the setup doesn't seem to be separate. Looks like, React application here is considered a part of Node.js application. If so, I'd suggest refactoring the logic and file structure, so that they become sibling apps.

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you want start React in development mode you need to set some scripts to do that. This is an example of package.json scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "set PORT=8080 && react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
```

In this way you can start with the `npm start` the development server for your client. You don't need to rebuild the project for every modification and serve it by the Express, that's just for production.

EDIT:
If you run your react with a dev server (using two different URL so) I think you should add some headers for your requests:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader(
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
        'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
    );
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE');

    next();
});
```

Comment: The challenge is that Express modifies the response to the client, so I need to run React via Express in dev, so I can see the same behaviour as when I load it in production. So I understand that I can just run `npm start` but then I don't get the modified response from Express (as express isn't sending the response).

Comment: Usually I work in dev mode with development server for my client also if the app is a combined one (client served by the API server on the same URL). I think your Express isn't sending response while in dev cause you should try to set some headers. I updated my answer. Is this could be your problem? If not could you provide an example of one of your http requests?

Answer (score 0):

> I have a React app

If you have access to its source files, you probably are using Webpack to at least bundle separate component files together (not to mention using plugins and loaders, e.g., Babel for JSX).

If so, using [`webpack-dev-server`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/#using-webpack-dev-server) would be the best option, as it is the solution for this exact kind of task. Keep in mind, that this is not a server configuration, but a client one (although dev-only). For other similar options see ["**Choosing a Development Tool**" section of Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/#choosing-a-development-tool).

---

If the task is to somehow make this reloading happen from the server (which it shouldn't, as it is development, but I might miss something), certainly, look at [`webpack-dev-middleware`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-dev-middleware). If that didn't work, I'm afraid, the solution might be complex, involving setting up watchers for groups of files, establishing client-to-server communications (WebSockets, for example), and triggering full-page or part-page reloads.

Comment: Express is modifying the response to the client, so I wanted to use Express in my dev environment, not webpack. I understand the reloading is happening from the client, but when using `npm build` on the React code it doesn't auto reload. Running `npm start` launches the webpack server, which I don't want, but I want the reloading to still happen. Maybe a better question would be - when I run `npm start` on a react app, where are the files stored?